# Initialise vector size within a map

Tags: c++, c++11

In my header file, I have a map field:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> priceSMA;
```

I know the length of the vector, which is 50. How do I go about setting the size of this vector?

If the field was a vector on it's own, It's simple to set the size. But since it's nested within a map I'm lost.

The below throws a syntax error for the vector length:

```
priceSMA = std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>(50)>();
```

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

For further clarification, the `prceSMA` key will be populated with a currency identifier, e.g. `"USD"`. The vector is to store the last 50 values of this currency, where each value has a certain timestamp. Once the first 50 values are populated, when we jump to the next timestamp all the current values in the vector shift over by one value, and populate the last (50th) item in the vector with the new value from the current timestamp.

Prior to the shift, I calculate the average of the 50 values in the vector and store this somewhere else.

The idea is to get a simple moving average over a certain time period.

Comment: not clear what you mean with "the vector". The map has no entries when you default construct it. Once you add elements to the map the vectors (one vector per element in the map, not *one* vector for the whole map) can have any size. Are you actually looking for `std::map<std::string,std::array<double,50>>` ?

Comment: in other words: Do you want a map that maps strings to arrays of fixed size 50 ?

Comment: That makes sense to me, I'm new to c++ and have only used vectors, just took a quick look at the array doc and this seems to be right for my needs. Thanks I'll give it a try!

Comment: if you can clarify the question, I could turn the comments into an answer. Try to explain what `priceSMA` is supposed to model. What are the elements of the map?

Comment: Just a side remark: I would double check whether values you want to store in the vectors should be `double`. Prices and currency exchange rates cannot be accurately represented by vars of type `double` and it's possible this will introduce errors into your software.
Rolling average of a price _can_ be a floating point value in some cases, but not always: if it would be used to derive another monetary value (like an average exchange rate calculated from 50 most recent exchange rates), then it most probably should be modelled with a data type able to hold decimal values up to some accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
priceSMA = std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>(50)>();
```

is not correct, because the size of a vector is not part of its type, but for the map, the second template parameter is the type of `mapped_value`. On a related note, you don't need to explicitly call the default construtor. The map is already default constructed:

```
std::map< key_type , mapped_value_type> priceSMA; // <- this is a default constructed map
```

There is not *one* vector, but each element in the map will have a vector of dynamic size. If you actually want to map strings to arrays of fixed size, take a look at [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and use something like this:

```
struct foo {
     std::map<std::string,std::array<double,50>> priceSMA;
     foo() {} // constructor, no need to explicitly call the default constructor
};
```

Because `std::map::operator[]` inserts elements when none is present for the provided key, you can then directly access element of the contained arrays like this:

```
int main(){
    foo f;
    f.priceSMA["blubb"][13] = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the size will stay 50, you can use `std::map<std::string,std::array<double,50>>`.

Otherwise, if you use a `vector`, each time you add an element to your map, you can initialize the vector with 50 elements equal to 0 with `myMap["newKey"] = std::vector<double>(50, 0)`;

Comment: nitpick: You cannot initialize an element that was created by `operator[]`. It is already initialized, you can only assign to it. better call `resize`

Comment: `myMap["newKey"].resize(50);`

Comment: why is it better to call resize ?

Answer (score -1):

```
     map<ll, vector<int>> mp;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        mp[i] = vector<int>(26);
    }
```

This worked for me !!